# UIFakeStoreWindow error: Can't add component 'Transform' to UIFakeStoreWindow

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I have IAP version 4.1.2 and simple 2D project.

I get the error `Can't add component 'Transform' to  because such a component is already added to the game object` when I click on IAP button, but the script still works anyway.

I have only one IAP button, in a success case it should print to the console the text `Works` otherwise `Error`.

See my hierarchy:
[image]

`ScriptObject` is a just empty game object with attached c# script Test, which contains only two methods:

```
class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PrintOk()
    {
        Debug.Log("Works!");
    }
    public void PrintError()
    {
        Debug.Log("Error!");
    }

}
```

`ButtonIAP` is a simple IAP button which should print to the console simple text (Works or Error) depends on was the click action completed successfully.

[image]

So when I click the IAP button the program output to the console

```
Can't add component 'Transform' to UIFakeStoreWindow because such a component is already added to the game object!
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update ()
```

After it UI fake store window appears and if I click YES option `PrintOk` method is invoked and the program output the the console `Works`

[image]

So the problems are:

1. what does the error mean?
2. why does it appear?
3. how to fix it?

Comment: `what does the error mean` looks like something is trying to do `AddComponent<Transform>` somewhere .. which makes no sense since there exists no GameObject in Unity without a `Transform` component anyway ... `how to fix it` unless it's a script you wrote there is probably not much to do about ... anyway it's just a warning .. I'd claim you can ignore it ;)

Comment: @derHugo `unless it's a script you wrote there` yes, it's not my script trying to add transform component. I created clean new simple project for special to avoid such cases

Comment: I'm actually implementing this now and this bug seems to be firing off multiple times on the callback function. Also, when I check "Buy" the window goes away then pops back up on its own throwing this same error.